# Issue with Ajax calls in Chrome Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax, frontend-error, chrome-browser

We are having an issue with `Ajax calls in Chrome (only)`. The gist of it is that 1 in 50 or so calls will `return a 500 error`.

> If I refresh the page, it works.

It does not appear to be tied to a specific script as it happens on the backend (creating an order, for example) and the front end (like adding to cart).

Any ideas? Anyone else has this issue?

First noticed it after switching hosting providers, but this could be a red herring as we've been doing a lot of dev work as well.

**Running Magento Ver. 2.2.0**

Here's the console with two different instances:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: @ben what's the error ajax message?

Comment: @IdhamChoudry there's no error message. Returns 500 error seen above

Comment: @ben it should have log, please check the log under `/var/log/exception.log` or web server log.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh there is nothing in that log. It's not throwing an exception